# Deleted ico and recreated with different data, icon cache wont update

Tags: winapi, ico

I have a ico on my desktop named `rawr.ico`.

I opened the desktop folder in file explorer:

[image]

I atomically overwrite this file with new ico data. I use this algorithm:

https://github.com/Noitidart/Icon-Container-Generator/blob/master/modules/workers/ICGenWorker.js#L1024-L1150

I linked it rather then pasting here, as I don't think this is the problem.

After I do this, the icon on the desktop doesn't update. Double clicking the icon to open it in file viewer, shows the icon contents updated.

As seen in this image:
[image]

I tried to get the desktop to update by running this:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, NULL, NULL);
```

This refreshes the whle icon cache. I notice icons in my taskbar flash. However on desktop stays the same visually.

I tried to update the item locally:

```
SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEITEM, SHCNF_PATHW,  &wcsPath, NULL);
```

However the icon does not visually update.

Anyone have any ideas whats up?

Comment: The icon cache is like that. Restart the machine.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Hahaha @theB . Aw dang I was hoping I could get it to update :( My users are horribly confused. Non techy group.